Retrieve Bitlocker key from within Ubuntu
I mistakenly deleted the Windows partition key from the Microsoft account, and Secure Boot asks for it after an OS update (as expected); but because of the dual-boot setup, I can normally access Ubuntu, which resides in the very same encrypted SSD; thus somehow the Bitlocker key is entered. Do you know any means to retrieve it from this Ubuntu session so I can save it again for good?
Thank you so much.
This is different from the other question in that here I have access to the encrypted drive, just through the Ubuntu session and / or partition. Is not an external drive. The keys must be somehow entered to log into Ubuntu. So there's perhaps a means to pull them out 'from whithin'? So to say.

This question is similar to: Can I recover a Bitlocker-encrypted disk without the key?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Did you shrink the Windows partition to install Ubuntu? Ubuntu does not use Bitlocker during installation. Your Ubuntu partition is either not encrypted or it is probably encrypted using LUKS.

Well. Nominally Bitlocker is turned on after Ubuntu has been installed alongside Windows. I guessed the whole drive is then encrypted, but I checked out another dual-boot machine and its not the case. The Ubuntu partition is not encrypted at all. So, yeah, seems that I can only erase and re start the Windows partition. Thx.
